# Alternative to switch -- replacing characters

Tags: java, switch-statement, stringbuilder

I was required to write a program for class which:

1. Accepted a .txt file
2. Convert numbers 0-9 in the file to their text equivalent (if the number is at beginning of sentence, use uppercase)
3. Print the finished sentences to a new file

**Example:**

```
The 8 eggs were separated into 3 groups.
```

Would be converted to:

```
The eight eggs were separated into three groups.
```

---

Currently I am using a (very) long switch statement with a `StringBuilder` to complete the task:

```
switch(sb.charAt(i)){
        case '0':
            if (i == 0)
                sb.replace(i, i+1, "Zero");
            else
                sb.replace(i, i+1, "zero");
            break;
        case '1':
            if (i == 0)
                sb.replace(i, i+1, "One");
            else
                sb.replace(i, i+1, "one");
            break;
        ..... 
}
```

There is a more advanced/efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: How large can your  numbers get to. Is it only 0-10 or possibly 0-999999999?

Comment: For this program, only 0-9. I will update the question.

Comment: see my solution below. The conversion of strNumbers to text, you don't really need to use 10 swtich statement or 10 if statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you're looking for `HashMap`. This can help:

1. Create static `HashMap<String, String> DIGITS` and use `put("0", "zero"); put("1", "one"); //etc..` to initialize it.
2. Split your input string using `string.split(" ")`; this will create an array of strings like this: `{"The","8","eggs",...}`.
3. Use `StringBuilder` to build an answer:

   ```
   for (String s : splitted) {
       if (DIGITS.contains(s))
           sb.append(DIGITS.get(s));
       else
           sb.append(s);
       sb.append(' ');
   }
   ```

Comment: You forgot to create your HashMap: `private static HashMap <String,String> h = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
Sting[] token = statement.split(" ");
String newStatement = "";
for(int x=0; x<token.length; x++){
    if(token[x].matches("[0-9]+"))
        newStatement  += convertToText(token[x]) + " ";
    else
        newStatement  += token[x] + " ";        
}

public static String converetToText(String str){
    String[] text = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven". "eight", "nine"};
    return text[Integer.parseInt(str)];
}
```

Your entire program is completed.

---

**Explanation:**

1. Split the given statement by spaces.
2. Store individual word into a string array (token[])
3. Check each individual word whether it is a number
4. If it is a number convert to text and add it to new statement.
5. If it is a text add it straight into your new statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Iterate through the characters using `Character.isDigit` to check if they should be replaced. If so simply look up the replacement string in an array using (character - `'0'`) as the index:

```
    String[] textArray =  new String[]{ "zero", "one", "two",
                                        "three", "four", "five",
                                        "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc 1 xyz 8");
    System.out.println(sb);

    for (int i=0; i<sb.length(); ++i) {
        char c = sb.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            sb.replace(i, i+1, textArray[c - '0']);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Output is:

```
abc 1 xyz 8
abc one xyz eight
```