# Replacing numbers with words

Tags: java, replace, stringbuilder

So I have a project for school that I am working on and was hoping you guys could look over my code and tell me what I may be doing wrong. I need all numbers 0-9 to be replaced with their word counterparts, but any number above that to stay the same.

this is the code now and my reasoning

Im at my wits end with the 12 not printing onetwo. Ive tried everything right now I havE

```
for (int i=0; i < stringBuilder.length(); i++)
  {
    if ((stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '0' || stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '1' || stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '2' || stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '3' || stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '4' || stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '5' ||            stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '6' ||
         stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '7' || stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '8' || stringBuilder.charAt(i) == '9')&& (stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '0' || stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '1' || stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '2' || stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '3' || stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '4'
         || stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '5' || stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '6' || stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '7' || stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '8' || stringBuilder.charAt(i-1) != '9') && (stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '0' || stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '1'
         || stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '2' || stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '3' || stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '4' || stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '5' || stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '6' || stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '7' || stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '8' || stringBuilder.charAt(i+1) == '9'))
       {
```

basically it first runs throught the for loop to find if any of the positions of i have these values then it does the position (i) - 1 to see if it the position before i is also one of the numbers, then it does the same for i + 1 however I get an error about a -1 value range being invalid or something. Can anyone offer help?

Comment: If you start at `i=0`, anywhere you pass `i - 1` to `charAt()` is going to give you an error about trying to get the `-1`th character.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799408/alternative-to-switch-replacing-characters

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28799565/2487403

Comment: Make use of `Character.isDigit(char)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you start with
 `i = 0`, you cannot use
 `charAt(i-1)` because -1 is an invalid index.